# Is it wise to use foreign key (MySQL) in this case?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, duplicates

still trying to get started in the world of databases, running into issues daily!

I have a table 'songs' which contains information on artists/tracks:

```
CREATE TABLE songs (
    song_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    artist_name varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    song_name varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    tag_fk SMALLINT,
    FOREIGN KEY (tag_fk) REFERENCES tags(tag_id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
) ENGINE = 'InnoDB';

CREATE TABLE tags (
    tag_id SMALLINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    tag_name varchar(255) UNIQUE
) ENGINE = 'InnoDB';
```

Now I have a foreign key in 'songs' referencing 'tags.tag_id', 'tags.tag_name' will later contain tags like 'lovesong', 'melancholic'. Now in certain cases a song can have more than one tag, so if its a melancholic lovesong it should have both tags. Though I just noticed I can not add two SMALLINT to tag_fk seperated by comma, it only allows one SMALLINT per row.

I figured I could add a new row to 'tag.tag_name' containing 'lovesong;melancholic' and later process it in php, splitting it by ';', but that is rather a less sexy solution to the problem, especially because the data is added by a program and I would have to deal with sorting the strings, too, so I wouldn't end up with duplicate tags like 'lovesong;melancholic' and 'melancholic;lovesong', which is basically the same.

How is that issue commonly solved? If I do replace 'songs.tag_fk' by a varchar column 'songs.tag' instead I will have tons of duplicate data, as there's gonna be a lot of "Lovesongs" and "Melancholic" songs in the database, so a foreign key solution is probably best.

I also thought about adding 'songs.tags_fk' and 'songs.tags_fk2' but thats rather a dirty hack, too. Especially if some songs start having more than 2, 3, 4 tags.

What's the best way to deal with that?

Comment: I would recommend reading up on database normalization. The wiki areticle about it is a great start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a many-to-many relationship. You require a third table to link the two. So that one song can have many tags, and one tag can be assigned to many songs.

http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/many-to-many-relationships/

Comment: In the example the output will be in two rows, is it possible to create a query whose output is sort of: artistname | songname | tag1, tag2?

Comment: Nevermind, should have used google before asking. [http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/1627806-concatenate-column-value-multiple-rows-into-single-column.html](http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/1627806-concatenate-column-value-multiple-rows-into-single-column.html)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a Many to Many table relationship.  You do this by creating a third table that has Foreign Keys for song_id and tag_id.

```
CREATE TABLE Song_Tag_Xref (
    FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES tags(tag_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (song_id) REFERENCES songs(song_id),
) ENGINE = 'InnoDB';
```

Then you can get all tags for a song by doing something like this:

```
select tags.tag_name 
from songs, song_tag_xref, tags 
where songs.song_id = song_tag_xref.song_id 
and song_tag_xref.tag_id = tags.tag_id
and songs.artist_name like 'Bob Marley'
```

Comment: Thank you, _Grant unwin_ pasted a link to a tutorial just like you described that 'many-to-many' relationship, I'll go with you guys' solution.